# Drawing a large number of graphs using Graphviz

Tags: python, networkx, graphviz, flowchart, pygraphviz

I want to use graphviz to generate a large number of graphs. Now I have a chart with 10 thousands data which indicate reaction fomulars, like:

a + b -> c;

e + f -> g
...

Is there any convenient way to convert the flow chart to graphs one by one by using graphviz? or any other tools?

```
digraph 1{
  node[shape="record"];
  edge[style="dashed"];

  a[style="filled",color="red",fillcolor="chartreuse"];
  b;
  c;
  d;
  a ->b;
  b ->d;
  c ->d[color="green"];
  d-> a;
}
```

Comment: Can you show an example of how you are generating one graph? The context is important for suggesting how to automate

Comment: digraph 1{

node[shape="record"];

edge[style="dashed"];


a[style="filled",color="red",fillcolor="chartreuse"];

b;

c;

a ->c;

b ->c[color="green"];

}

Comment: I posted in my question

Comment: I still fail to understand. You want _what_ to be converted to the dot language? Can we see an example of your input data? You quoted a piece of output apparently. (Related: take a look at the PlantUML library.)

Comment: I have a lot of formula equations, like: 
a + b -> c and so on, and I want to convert them to graphs using graphviz, while there are almost 10 thousands of equations so I can barely draw the graph one by one.

Comment: This does not look like a `graphviz` issue. You probably need to transform the file(s) using another tool into one or many `dot` files. As @9000 had asked, pls give us a sample of your input data. One or many files? How are the sections that you convert into graphs separated from each other in the file?